# Streaming large multi-part uploads to S3 using AmazonS3Client

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

An upload stream given to `AmazonS3Client` must be seekable. You can make a `Stream` seekable using `AmazonS3Util.MakeStreamSeekable`. However, the [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Util/AmazonS3Util.cs#L262) of this reveals that it will not perform well with large streams:

```cs
        public static System.IO.Stream MakeStreamSeekable(System.IO.Stream input)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream output = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            const int readSize = 32 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[readSize];

            int count = 0;
            using (input)
            {
                while ((count = input.Read(buffer, 0, readSize)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }

            output.Position = 0;
            return output;
        }
```

So, what approaches are available to upload a `Stream` to S3 *without* copying the entire contents into memory?

Answer (score 0):

Each chunk must be a seekable `Stream`, but you can have many chunks. The solution is to split up the input `Stream`.